# apache partition to different drives

Tags: apache, data-structures, partitioning

I m running Apache server 2.2.

I am developing a site , locally on my laptop and now I have to transfer it to the server.

A colleague told me that I should "split" Apache. That way the configs and logs and the files of the site(`.html`, `.php`) are in one drive (C:), but the folder that the user uploads multimedia are in another drive (D:).

This adds flexibility to the system, because if extra space for the multimedia is needed we can just update/replace (D:), without messing with the whole site.

How do I do that? Is there a tutorial for "splitting" Apache?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe any professional would host using a filesystem that supports growth and multiple volume spanning.
A way to solve this particular issue could be to use Virtual hosts in Apache, such that you may have subdomains such as usercontent.mysite.tld
You may also want to host static files using a more lightweight httpd such as thttpd or lighthttpd, you would typically put this on static.mysite.tld

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/